# Buy/Sell signal until 5 bars condition Trigger

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, multiple-conditions

I'm having trouble writing a script. My strategy is based on two conditions:

1°- When CCI crosses over -110 or under 110 first condition is trigger.

2°- The 2 SMA needs to cross at a range of 5 bars, after the first condition was triggered to a trigger a "BUY" or "SELL"

I haven't programming experience, the little I learned was researching I'll be grateful if you can help me.

```
enter code here
```

/// BUY AND SELL RULES

BS1 = ta.crossover(CCI,-110)
SS1 = ta.crossunder(CCI, 110)

BUY = ta.crossover(sslUp, sslDown) ///if ta.barssince(BS1,5)\\- //i don't know how to fit that last condition in the script

SELL = ta.crossover(sslUp, sslDown) ///if ta.barssince(BS1,5)\\

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.
You're looking for the `and` keyword. If you use `and`, both conditions need to be `true` in order to return `true` (and the trigger `BUY` variable).

Keep in mind that `ta.barssince()` has only one parameter and this function returns the number of bars since the last time the condition was true.

```
BS1 = ta.crossover(CCI,-110) 
SS1 = ta.crossunder(CCI, 110)

BUY = ta.crossover(sslUp, sslDown) and ta.barssince(BS1) <= 5
SELL = ta.crossover(sslUp, sslDown) and ta.barssince(BS1)<= 5
```